# Performing conditional (aka lookup) functions using two data frames?

Tags: r

I'm hoping someone can help me with this challenge (I'm fairly new to R). I have one data frame (Plots) that has unique records for tree species (Spp) and tree size (Dbh). I have a second data frame (Parameters) that gives parameters (X and Y) for a function for each species.

```
Plots
Id  Spp Dbh
414 SM  27.2
415 BE  17.4
416 YB  35.8
418 SM  43.5
419 SM  53.3
420 SM  53.3
421 SM  11.9
422 TL  27.5
423 XS  13.2

Parameters
Species X   Y
BE  1   10
SM  2   20
YB  3   30
OTH 4   40
```

I need look at every record of `Plots$Spp` and perform a simple function on `Plots$Dbh` using the `X` and `Y` records from `Parameters` (i.e. `X * Dbh^Y`) for the corresponding `Species`. If `Plots$Spp` has a record that is not in `Parameters$Species` (i.e. XS or TL), I need to use the X and Y values for OTH.

I first tried using `merge()` but couldn't get it to work with the XS/OTH situation. I also tried a for loop with nested if/else if/else, but again I failed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

Plots %>%
  mutate(Species = ifelse(Spp %in% Parameters$Species, Spp, "OTH")) %>%
  left_join(Parameters)
```

create a new variable `"Species"` in `Plots` data frame by first checking if `Plots$Spp` is in `Parameters$Species` if yes leave `Spp`, if not replace with `"OTH"` and then join the resulting data frame with `Parameters` by `"Species"` column.

```
#output
   Id Spp  Dbh Species X  Y
1 414  SM 27.2      SM 2 20
2 415  BE 17.4      BE 1 10
3 416  YB 35.8      YB 3 30
4 418  SM 43.5      SM 2 20
5 419  SM 53.3      SM 2 20
6 420  SM 53.3      SM 2 20
7 421  SM 11.9      SM 2 20
8 422  TL 27.5     OTH 4 40
9 423  XS 13.2     OTH 4 40
```

data:

```
Plots <- read.table(text = "Id  Spp Dbh
414 SM  27.2
415 BE  17.4
416 YB  35.8
418 SM  43.5
419 SM  53.3
420 SM  53.3
421 SM  11.9
422 TL  27.5
423 XS  13.2", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Parameters <- read.table(text = "Species X   Y
BE  1   10
SM  2   20
YB  3   30
OTH 4   40", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```